# What does "ArangoError 4: Builder value not yet sealed" exactly mean, when making a transaction in Foxx?

Tags: transactions, arangodb, foxx

I am trying to implement transactions in my Foxx app, I am using classes to manage database objects and have being trying to use these classes in the transaction action.

I cannot manage to go past that error message, I am including in the transaction module all that is needed, but I cannot manage to make it work.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: `ArangoError 4` is an internal error that is not expected to happen.
It would be useful to get further information about this, e.g. what version of ArangoDB are you actually using, when exactly does this error occur (at what exact action) and what the transaction code actually does... A code snippet that shows the problem would be ideal for reproduction.

Comment: Please collect log files with and create a github issue. This would be much appreciated.